# cakePHP and IIS8.5 : HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: cakephp, iis, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

When I browse to localhost/admin/videos/view/1 I get the page I want. I also want that page to show when I browse to localhost/videos/view/1.

But it gives me error message :

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Detailed Error Information:

Module        IIS Web Core
Notification  MapRequestHandler
Handler       StaticFile
Error Code    0x80070002
Requested URL http://{my-ip}/app/webroot/videos/view/1
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\{my-project}\app\webroot\videos\view\1
Logon Method  Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous
```

These are my rules in the web.config file :

```
<rule name="Rewrite requests to test.php" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^test.php(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/test.php{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Exclude direct access to app/webroot/*" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^app/webroot/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
   <action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rewrite routed access to assets(img, css, files, js, fonts, vid, favicon)" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(img|css|files|js|fonts|vid|favicon.ico)(.*)$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule>
 <rule name="Rewrite requested file/folder to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>
```

**Update :**

It has something to do with

`<match url="^(img|css|files|js|fonts|vid|favicon.ico)(.*)$" />`

When I cut the vid| (that is the directory of my videos) it shows localhost/videos/view/1.

But then I have the problem that it doesn't load my video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done to resolve this:

**1** I deleted the |vid inside

```
<match url="^(img|css|files|js|fonts|favicon.ico)(.*)$" />
```

**2** I replaced the vid folder inside my webroot to the files folder because that folder is standard there.

**3** I changed the src to the video in my view

```
<source src="/files/vid/...
```